# How to upload file from SD card by Micro SD adapter to ftp server using Filezilla?

Tags: arduino-mega

I use Arduino Mega 2560 to send a file stored in a micro sd by a module "Micro SD adapter" to ftp server. I use the sim800l evb v2.0 module and I proceeded as follows:

I insert the AT command :

```
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","internet"

AT+SAPBR=1,1

AT+FTPCID=1

AT+FTPTYPE="I"

AT+FTPMODE=0

AT+FTPSERV="197.158.86.105"

AT+FTPPORT=42

AT+FTPUN="user"

AT+FTPPW="password"

AT+FTPPUTNAME="test.txt"

AT+FTPPUTPATH="/"

AT+FTPPUT=1
```

Results :

```
+FTPPUT:1,62
```

sometimes `+FTPPUT:1,63`
or `+FTPPUT:1,64`
or `+FTPPUT:1,65`
or `+FTPPUT:1,78`

what do I have to do. Please, can anyone help me? thank you

Comment: Maybe the next step is to send the data? I don't see what a load of AT commands have to do with an SD card adaptor and an Arduino. Do you have some kind of (unspecified) GSM module attached? Or a network device? Please give us *all* the information, not just a few random snippets.

Comment: Indeed, I'm sorry, yes I forgot to mention that I use the sim800l evb v2.0 module

Comment: And what does the datasheet or manual for that module tell you about performing an FTPPUT session?

Comment: yes, I have the AT command manual and I applied it

Comment: But it does not work :<error>
 62 DNS error
 63 Connect error
 64 Timeout
 65 Server error
 78 Upload error

Comment: Well, then you have some pointers to start debugging your connection.

Comment: thank you, exactly, I am aware of the bugs but I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Check some points: Is there a FTP server running on the server device "197.158.86.105"? Or just a ssh server for sftp? Are you allowed to used a IP address instead a FQN like "ftp.example.org" with the command `AT+FTPSERV`.  The standard ftp port is 21. You use 42 is that intended? I don't see something like `AT-FTPOPEN` or `AT-FTPCONNECT`. Is this done implicitly or did you forget it? (I don't say there are such commands. But normally you have to connect to a ftp server and to establish a session.)

Comment: Thank you for your attention. As far as I know, no, no FTP server isn't running on this device. Since I don't have a domain name yet, so I have to mention an IP adress but I'm going to take a closer look. And yes, the use of port 42 is normal. AT+FTPPUT= 1 is the command that starts the connection to the server. Thank you

Comment: So if there is no ftp server running on the target, the problem is quite clear. Also, using port 42 for ftp is not "normal", as mentioned by Peter Paul Kiefer you should try port 21 or 22 (sftp) once you have a server running.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try.